# List of dataframes in a loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, loops

I have list of data frames, a list of 279 elements and each element is made of 10 data frames.
So for example List_DATA[0][9] gives me the 9th data frame of the first list. I am trying to create a different list of data "List_Selected" in a loop using the values of "List_DATA":

```
List_Selected=[]
for i in range(0,279):
    List_Selected_temp=[]
    for j in range(0,10):
        List_Selected_temp.append(List_DATA[i][j][(List_DATA[i][j]['A']>3) & (List_DATA[i][j]['A']<5)])
        List_Selected.append(List_Selected_temp)
```

The problem is in the end I get identical data-frames values for all the 279 lists. So I have a bug somewhere and I cannot find it.I guess the lists are being overwritten, can anyone maybe spot the mistake in my code?

Comment: I think (I could be wrong, of course) you want to remove one indentation of ``List_Selected.append(List_Selected_temp)`` so that it is appending in ``for i`` instead of inside ``for j``

Comment: @Karina, Thank you for your comment, you're right. Could you please write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List_Selected=[]
for i in range(0,279):
    List_Selected_temp=[]
    for j in range(0,10):
        df = List_DATA[i][j]
        List_Selected_temp.append(df.loc[(df['A']>3) & (df['A']<5)]
    List_Selected.append(List_Selected_temp)
```

Comment: @the phoenix let me know if my answer helps you solve your problem.

Comment: @naturoArea51, thank you for your answer and help, unfortunately it did not work. The mistake was found.

Comment: @thephoenix that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

A nice upgrade in terms of runtime that uses Python's multiprocess:
Using concurrent module

```
import concurrent

def paralel_cond_func(curr_list_data):
    List_Selected_temp=[]
    for j in range(0,10):
        List_Selected_temp.append(curr_list_data[j][(curr_list_data[j]['A']>3) & (curr_list_data[j]['A']<5)])
    return List_Selected_temp

# number of processes
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(10)

futures = [executor.submit(paralel_cond_func, group)
           for group in List_DATA]

concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
List_Selected = [res.result() for res in futures]
```

Answer (score 0):

`List_Selected.append(...)` should be outside of the `for j` loop, but inside of the `for i` loop.

```py
List_Selected=[]
for i in range(0,279):
    List_Selected_temp=[]
    for j in range(0,10):
        List_Selected_temp.append(List_DATA[i][j][(List_DATA[i][j]['A']>3) & (List_DATA[i][j]['A']<5)])
    List_Selected.append(List_Selected_temp)
```

Having it inside the `for j` loop making it appending 279*10 times, which is most probably unwanted behavior.